# Why is my if statement still running if the condition is false? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, if-statement

Why is when `if(Session["StudentRep"] == null)` is false the if statement still running?
In the above code the if does work! Why is that happening?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%#Eval("lesDate")%> </td>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%# Eval("lesHour") %> </td>
            <%if (Session["StudentRep"] != null)
                { %>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%# (TeacherById(Eval("teacherID").ToString())).Name %>  </td>
            <%} %>

             **<% if (Session["StudentRep"] == null)
                { %>

           <td style="width: 200px"><%# StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).Name+" "+  StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).FamilyName%></td>
            <%} %>**

            <td style="width: 200px"><%# (CityName((int)Eval("CityNum"))) %>  </td>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%# SubName((int)Eval("subID"))+ " " +SubDif((int)Eval("subID")).ToString()+" '??" %></td>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%# Eval("participant") %></td>
            <td style="width: 200px"><%# Eval("cost") %> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The session might not be null, it could be empty or nothing. Try using the IsNullOrEmpty function.

```
            <%if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["StudentRep"] as string)) { %>

            <% } %>
```

Comment: it still jump to this -->
<%# StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).Name+" "+  StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).FamilyName%>

maybe the problem in this sentence

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["StudentRep"] as string))
{ %>
     <td style="width: 200px"><%# (TeacherById(Eval("teacherID").ToString())).Name %>  </td>
<%} else { %>
     <td style="width: 200px"><%# StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).Name+" "+  StudentById(Eval("studentID").ToString()).FamilyName%></td>
<%} %>
```

If it still renders the incorrect TD then the chances are that StudentRep does actually have a value.